# Setting R plot xlim with only the lower bound

Tags: r

Suppose I have created a simple plot like this:

```
xvalues <- 100:200
yvalues <- 250:350
plot(xvalues, yvalues)
```

[image]

However, **I would like the x-axis to start at 0** and leave the upper bound to be whatever is computed by R. How can I do this?

I know there is an option for xlim=c(lower bound, upper bound), but I don't know what the upper bound is. Also, I am evidently unable to let the upper bound be unspecified:

```
> plot(xvalues, yvalues, xlim=c(0))
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

It would be great if I didn't have to compute the max value of the xvalues vector in order to get the upper bound, as that seems wasteful for a very large data vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use one of two approaches:

**Calculating the limits**

```
xlim <- c(0, max(xvalues))
```

`xlim` can now be supplied as the `xlim`argument in `plot`.

```
xvalues <- 100:200
yvalues <- 250:350
plot(xvalues, yvalues, xlim=xlim)
```

[image]

**Let `par` return the limits**

This one is a bit more sophisticated, but sometimes helpful (certainly overkill in your case, but for completeness). You plot the data once, you get the limits of the plotting area in user coordinates using `par("usr")`. Now you can use these in your new plot.

```
plot(xvalues, yvalues, xaxs="i")
xmax <- par("usr")[2]
plot(xvalues, yvalues, xlim=c(0,xmax))
```

PS. I used `xaxs="i"` so the results will be without small extensions at the ends.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding using max() to set the xlim, I would prefer not to run max(), as it seems wasteful to call that on a very large data set.

Comment: Hhm, I can't think of a way to avoid this. But the `max` function  is superfast. It will take max less than 200 milliseconds for a vector with 100 million entries, try `x <- rnorm(1e8); system.time(max(x))`. So your data must be HUGE if that will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just seems like a waste of CPU cycles. :P

Answer (score 1):

you can simply set the max for `x` using the max of you values:

```
xvalues <- 1:99
yvalues <- rep(1,99)


plot(xvalues, yvalues, xlim = c(0, max(xvalues)) )
```

[image]